# File exist not working in laravel for a file that right there

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7

In my laravel project, I have a form for uploading a file and removing it.
I create a disk in config/filesystem:

```
'upload' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => public_path(),
            'url' => env('APP_URL'),
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
```

Here uploading file work correctly but when I want remove them from public folder the file not exist:

```
$img_path = public_path( $this->directory . '/' . $this->getFliename());
$img_path = str_replace( "/",'\\', $img_path); // checked with it & without it

// $img_path= "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\final\public\upload\users\1\5bc722d2b7c05.jpg"

dump(File::exists($img_path)); // it always return false

// and then which one
File::delete($img_path); 
Storage::disk('upload')->delete($img_path);
```

why this file doesn't exist, and which one for deleting a file is true?

It becomes more complicating when I do it with route???

```
// testing ...
Route::get('/test', function (){
   File::delete('C:\Users\Me\Desktop\final\public\upload\users\1\5bc722d2b7c05.jpg');
});
```

Comment: add your code for storing file

Comment: I use $file->storeAs() @SaurabhMistry, It works properly I find it in public folder and in it url

Comment: Actually in this path "public/upload/users/id"

Comment: Have you tried changing the file permissions and/or ownership of the file in question?

Comment: No, I didn't @Goose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file might exist on the filesystem, but the web user that PHP is running under might not have permission to read, update, or delete the file.

On a linux or mac system, you'll typically want to give the web user ownership of the file, and set file permissions to 664 and folder permissions to 775.

644 and 755 should also work and give you slightly stricter permissions.

If the above fails, try 777 just to debug, but do not do that on production as it's a serious security issue.

I'm not sure how it is done on Windows, but hopefully this gets you on the right path.

Comment: I know it's old, but for me in Windows it somehow didn't work (using Storage::exists($path)) and I'm using WAMPSERVER, check for the permissions, it's fine. idk what make it error.

Answer (score 1):

As you are storing images in public/upload folder :

```
$user_id= $user->id;
$file_name=$user->image;
$img_path=public_path('upload/users/'.$user_id. '/' .$filename);

if(is_file($img_path)){
   unlink($img_path);
   // or File::delete($img_path);  
}else{
    echo "File does not exist";
}
```

Comment: Thank u for your response buddy, I test it, it didn't work :(

Comment: try to `dd($imagepath)` , show me what you are getting

Comment: I think you are not getting correct path , otherwise `unlink` will definetly work

Answer (score 1):

Your $img_path appears to be set with the full path to the file, rather than a path relative to the base of your specified disk that would have been returned by `$file->storeAs()` when you saved the file.

This should work:

`Storage::disk('upload')->delete('upload/users/1/5bc722d2b7c05.jpg')`

If you need the full path on disk for some reason, try this:

`Storage::disk('upload')->path('upload/users/1/5bc722d2b7c05.jpg')`

Check if the file exists:

`Storage::disk('upload)->exists('upload/users/1/5bc722d2b7c05.jpg')`
OR `File::exists(Storage::disk('upload')->path('upload/users/1/5bc722d2b7c05.jpg'))`

(returns `C:\Users\Me\Desktop\final\public\upload/users/1/5bc722d2b7c05.jpg` because your 'upload' disk has a base of `public_path()`)

Read/write permissions for the web server could also come into play, depending on your server configuration. Typically you would not store things directly in the `public/` folder, but rather in `storage/app/public` and use `php artisan storage:link` to generate a symbolic link to the storage directory. You can read more here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/filesystem#the-public-disk

As a side note, Windows accepts either `/` or `\`, so using `/` makes your scripts much easier to use on other systems and reduces headaches in string escaping.